# Finding file by name recursively, deleting it and creating a symlink

Tags: find, symlink

Given:

Folder structure as (`file.txt` are plain text files in each directory, not symlinks):

```
/basedir/A/file.txt
/basedir/B/file.txt
/basedir/C/file.txt
```

The same `file.txt` that sits in `/mydir`:

```
/mydir/file.txt
```

I need a command that would run from `/basedir` that:

- Finds recursively all `/file.txt` (in `.A/`, `./B` and `./C`)
- Removes found `file.txt` files
- Creates a symlink to `/mydir/file.txt`

Can that be done in a single bash command?

Thank you!

Comment: Is `file.txt` the same file over all the directories or just any `.txt` ?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
find /basedir -type f -name file.txt -exec ln -sf /mydir/file.txt '{}' \;
```

This finds all files named `file.txt` under `/basedir`, and runs `ln` on each to replace it (`-f`) with a symbolic link (`-s`) to `/mydir/file.txt`.